# Old-ish first post showed up in review queue

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, review

I was just checking the First Posts review queue, and I found this post:

https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/146862/many-body-quantum-rotors#

Strange that it should be there, given that it's from mid-November and I haven't seen it before.

Does anyone have an idea why it was there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The author's [*original* first post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/145449/general-gaussian-distribution-relation) was migrated to a different site some time ago, and the system just now got around to cleaning up the stub.

That makes the *second* post from that author the new first. Which is why you were presented with it.

This is reasonably common.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense.